# sum array value and capture each index output on php

Tags: php

i have problem with array calculation

like this one

```
array 
[0] => 3
[1] => 2
[2] => 4
```

i want to get calculation value for each sum on array like this

```
a= 0;
foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $a += $sv;
}
```

so the output be like

```
[0] => 3 // means 3+0
[1] => 5 // means array[0] + array[1] = 3+2 = 5
[2] => 9 // means array[0] + array[1] + array[2] = 3+2+4 = 9
```

how i capture each loop output as and array, please help

```
output
[0] => 3 
[1] => 5 
[2] => 9
```

thanks..

Comment: What?? And what is `$sv`?

Comment: Initialize a new array before the loop, and then add the value of $a as a new element inside it …? `$newArray[] = $a;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple loop accumulating a total and then storing that accumulated total in  a new array occurance each time round the loop like this

```
$array = [3,2,4];
$tot_arr = [];
$tot = 0;
foreach ($array as $ar) {
    $tot += $ar;
    $tot_arr[] = $tot; 
}
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 9
)
```

Comment: thank you very much dude, sorry late response i got busy on other work